# passing data to subprocess.check_output

Tags: python

I want to invoke a script, piping the contents of a string to its stdin and retrieving its stdout.

I don't want to touch the real filesystem so I can't create real temporary files for it.

using `subprocess.check_output` I can get whatever the script writes; how can I get the input string into its stdin though?

```
subprocess.check_output([script_name,"-"],stdin="this is some input")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1043, in _get_handles
    p2cread = stdin.fileno()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Comment: The `stdin` arg for `check_output()` must be a file object, not a string.

Comment: @jdi obviously; so how to give it something that quacks like a file but isn't a file?

Comment: By choosing @larsmans answer :-) its a lot easier if you don't try to overuse the `check_output` convenience function and just do a normal Popen + communicate. Otherwise you would be expected to open your own pipe manually before hand, and then pass that to the `check_output(stdin)` and then write to it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `Popen.communicate` instead of `subprocess.check_output`.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen([script_name, "-"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate("this is some input")
```

Comment: This depends on the tool. Some are designed to read standard input if you call them without arguments, others want an explicit dash (and many will accept a dash as standard input if they accept multiple file name arguments).

Comment: This is not really correct any longer; in Python 3.5+ you can do this easily with `subprocess.run()`

Answer (score 31):

In Python 3.4 and newer, you can use the *input* keyword parameter to send input via STDIN when using `subprocess.check_output()`

Quoting from [the standard library documentation for `subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

> The *input* argument is passed to `Popen.communicate()` and thus to the
>   subprocess’s stdin. If used it must be a byte sequence, or a string if
>   `universal_newlines=True`. When used, the internal `Popen` object is
>   automatically created with `stdin=PIPE`, and the *stdin* argument may not
>   be used as well.

Example:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["sed", "-e", "s/foo/bar/"],
...                         input=b"when in the course of fooman events\n")
b'when in the course of barman events\n'
>>> 
>>> # To send and receive strings instead of bytes,
>>> # pass in universal_newlines=True
>>> subprocess.check_output(["sed", "-e", "s/foo/bar/"],
...                         universal_newlines=True,
...                         input="when in the course of fooman events\n")
'when in the course of barman events\n'
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass input to subprocess.check_output() as demonstrated here in python 2.7? I know that the input option is not able to be used but subprocess.communicate(...) is not passing my input as expected and I seem to have no other option.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a check_output backported version for python 2.7 with input.

```
from subprocess import (PIPE, Popen, CalledProcessError)

def check_output_input(*popenargs, **kwargs):
    """Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

    If the exit code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError.  The
    CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode
    attribute and output in the output attribute.

    The arguments are the same as for the Popen constructor.  Example:

    >>> check_output(["ls", "-l", "/dev/null"])
    'crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Oct 18  2007 /dev/null\n'

    The stdout argument is not allowed as it is used internally.
    To capture standard error in the result, use stderr=STDOUT.

    >>> check_output(["/bin/sh", "-c",
    ...               "ls -l non_existent_file ; exit 0"],
    ...              stderr=STDOUT)
    'ls: non_existent_file: No such file or directory\n'

    There is an additional optional argument, "input", allowing you to
    pass a string to the subprocess's stdin.  If you use this argument
    you may not also use the Popen constructor's "stdin" argument, as
    it too will be used internally.  Example:

    >>> check_output(["sed", "-e", "s/foo/bar/"],
    ...              input=b"when in the course of fooman events\n")
    b'when in the course of barman events\n'

    If universal_newlines=True is passed, the return value will be a
    string rather than bytes.

    """
    if 'stdout' in kwargs:
        raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
    if 'input' in kwargs:
        if 'stdin' in kwargs:
            raise ValueError('stdin and input arguments may not both be used.')
        inputdata = kwargs['input']
        del kwargs['input']
        kwargs['stdin'] = PIPE
    else:
        inputdata = None
    process = Popen(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, **kwargs)
    try:
        output, unused_err = process.communicate(inputdata)
    except:
        process.kill()
        process.wait()
        raise
    retcode = process.poll()
    if retcode:
        cmd = kwargs.get("args")
        if cmd is None:
            cmd = popenargs[0]
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    return output
```

Comment: it would be great if this could get stderr too!