# python StringIO doesn't work as file with subrpocess.call()

Tags: python, file, console, stringio

I'm working with `subprocess` package to call some external console commands from a python script, and I need to pass file handlers to it to get **stdout** and **stderr** back separately. The code looks like this roughly:

```
import subprocess

stdout_file = file(os.path.join(local_path, 'stdout.txt'), 'w+')
stderr_file = file(os.path.join(local_path, 'stderr.txt'), 'w+')

subprocess.call(["somecommand", "someparam"], stdout=stdout_file, stderr=stderr_file)
```

This works fine and txt files with relevant output are getting created. Yet it would be nicer to handle these outputs in memory omitting files creation. So I used StringIO package to handle it this way:

```
import subprocess
import StringIO

stdout_file = StringIO.StringIO()
stderr_file = StringIO.StringIO()

subprocess.call(["somecommand", "someparam"], stdout=stdout_file, stderr=stderr_file)
```

But this doesn't work. Fails with:

```
  File "./test.py", line 17, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["somecommand", "someparam"], stdout=stdout_file, stderr=stderr_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1063, in _get_handles
    c2pwrite = stdout.fileno()
AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute 'fileno'
```

I see that it's missing some parts of the native file object and fails because of that.

So the question is more educational than practical - why these parts of file interface are missing from StringIO and are there any reasons why this cannot be implemented?

Comment: This is sort of what `subprocess.check_output` is for.

Comment: hmm, thing is that `subprocess.check_output` throws out all output as one string, while I need to separate **stdout** from **stderr**

Comment: hmm, found a workaround using Popen instead of subprocess. Explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103551/passing-data-to-subprocess-check-output

Comment: selffix - Popen is a part of subprocess, so instead of subprocess.call() or subprocess.check_output()

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903501/attributeerror-stringio-instance-has-no-attribute-fileno. Yes, this is a bug in the standard library.

Comment: Original post was done in 2013. Solution for this problem is not on my priority list anymore, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 10):

As you said in your comment, `Popen` and `Popen.communicate` are the right solution here.

A bit of background: real file objects have file descriptors, which is the `fileno` attribute `StringIO` objects are missing. They're just ordinary integers: you may be familiar with file descriptors 0, 1 and 2, which are `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`, respectively. If a process opens more files, they're assigned 3, 4, 5, etc.. You can take a look at a process's current file descriptors with `lsof -p`.

So, why can't `StringIO` objects have file descriptors? In order to get one, it'd need to either open a file or open a pipe*. Opening a file wouldn't make sense, since *not* opening files is the whole point of using `StringIO` in the first place.

And opening a pipe also wouldn't make sense, even though they live in memory like `StringIO` objects do. They're for communication, not storage: `seek`, `truncate`, and `len` have no meaning at all for pipes, and `read` and `write` behave very differently than they do for files. When you `read` from a pipe, the returned data is deleted from the pipe's buffer, and if that (relatively small) buffer is full when you try to `write`, your process will hang until something `read`s from the pipe to free up buffer space.

So if you want to use a string as `stdin`, `stdout` or `stderr` for a subprocess, `StringIO` won't cut it but `Popen.communicate` is perfect. As stated above (and warned about in `subprocess`'s docs), reading from and writing to pipes correctly is complicated. `Popen` handles that complexity for you.

* I guess I could theoretically imagine a third kind of file descriptor corresponding to a memory region shared between processes? Not really sure why that doesn't exist. But eh, I'm not a kernel developer, so I'm sure there's a reason.

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) is misleading. It says that the value of `stdout` can be "*an existing [file object](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-file-object)*", not mentioning that it requires the file object to have a `fileno`.

Comment: The traceback is also unnecessarily cryptic, if subprocess adds specific requirements on the file object then a good error message should be detected early and express that rather than accepting whatever duck-typing happens to throw at you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the `stdout` or `stderr` to a `StringIO` in real-time, you will have to do it concurrently. Here is an example using `asyncio` in Python 3.11:

```
import asyncio
import io
from subprocess import SubprocessError

# Maximum number of bytes to read at once from the 'asyncio.subprocess.PIPE'
_MAX_BUFFER_CHUNK_SIZE = 1024

# Buffers for stdout and stderr
stdout_buffer = io.StringIO()
stderr_buffer = io.StringIO()

async def run_cmd_async(command, check=False):
    process = await asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec(
        *command,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

    async def write_stdout() -> None:
        assert process.stdout is not None
        while chunk := await process.stdout.read(_MAX_BUFFER_CHUNK_SIZE):
            stdout_buffer.write(chunk.decode())

    async def write_stderr() -> None:
        assert process.stderr is not None
        while chunk := await process.stderr.read(_MAX_BUFFER_CHUNK_SIZE):
            stderr_buffer.write(chunk.decode())

    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as task_group:
        task_group.create_task(write_stdout())
        task_group.create_task(write_stderr())

        exit_code = await process.wait()
        if check and exit_code != 0:
            raise SubprocessError(
                f"Command '{command}' returned non-zero exit status {exit_code}."
            )
    return exit_code


# Run your command and print output
asyncio.run(run_cmd_async(["somecommand", "someparam"], check=True))
print(stdout_buffer.getvalue())
print(stderr_buffer.getvalue())
```

Then you could add a separate asynchronous task that gets the current value of the stdout and stderr buffers to do something with them in real-time.

Answer (score -3):

I think that you are expecting some other process to know how to read the memory as a stream from your main process. Perhaps if you can pipe your stream into the standard input and pipe the standard output into your stream you might be successful.